# Can't bind Drop-down values from Model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC concepts.I am currently working in Web forum Technology.So when I am doing  MVC project facing the issue like below.
My model class consists code like below:

```
 public class Dropdown
 {
    public List<string> drpid;
    public List<string> drpname;
 }
```

And datacontext class is

```
public class DataContext
{       
    Dropdown drp = new Dropdown();
    public Dropdown Bind_Dropdown()
    {
        drp.drpid =new List<string> { "1", "2" };           
        drp.drpname=new List<string>{"Mumbai","Bangalore"};
        return drp;
    }
}
```

And controller code is

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
       DataContext dt=new DataContext();
       var res = dt.Bind_Dropdown();
        return View("Index",res);
    }
```

And finally **Strongly typed view** with modal class **Dropdown** is

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Class.Dropdown

 @{
    Layout = null;
  }

 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>   
 <p>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.drpname, null);  @*Error here*@
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |

 </p>
</body>
```

Here can't bind dropdown values from modal class.Getting error 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'drpname',in view as shown above.
Dropdown properties are

- drpid as Data Value field
- drpname as Data Text field

So how to fix it.?

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes

Have a model class

```
public class Model1
{
  public string drpid {get; set;}
  public string drpname {get; set;} 
}


 public class Dropdown
 {
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> models { get; set; }
 }
```

Populate in DataContext

```
public class DataContext
{       
    public List<Model1> Bind_Dropdown()
    {
        List<Model1> modellist = new List<Model1> { new Model1 {drpid="1", drpname= "Mumbai"},
                                          new Model1 {drpid="2", drpname= "Bangalore"}};           
        return modellist;
    }
}
```

Action method

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
       DataContext dt=new DataContext();
       var res = dt.Bind_Dropdown();
       Dropdown drp = new Dropdown();
       drp.models = res.modellist.Select(m => new SelectListItem {Value = m.drpid, Text = m.drpname}).ToList();

        return View("Index",drp);
    }
```

In view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.models.Model1.drpid, Model.models)
```

Comment: Sorry..Can't convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable',because it is not delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

With SelectLists, you're probably better off creating a list of cities as a class, and iterating through those.  You can add SelectListItems to a SelectList.  This is probably not the best way to get your items to bind, but I did this with your code:

Model (adding SelectList as third property):

```
public class Dropdown
{
    public List<string> drpid;
    public List<string> drpname;
    public SelectList items;
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DataContext dt = new DataContext();
        Dropdown res = dt.Bind_Dropdown();

        IList <SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < res.drpname.Count; i++)
        {
            var selectListItem = new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = res.drpid[i],
                Text = res.drpname[i]
            };

            selectList.Add(selectListItem);
        }

        res.items = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");

        return View("Index", res);
    }
```

Then changed the DropDownFor helper in your view to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.drpid, Model.items, "")
```

This gets your dropdown list to show, and you can select.  But again, this is a quick fix, and there are better solutions.

Comment: I like Rahul's answer below as you don't have to deal with a for loop in the controller.  My solution above kept your properties in the Dropdown class as Lists, but the way Rahul is doing with by refactoring out a separate model class and then having a single list of SelectListItems is the better way to go.